# Reading different data on a single line from file in VHDL

Tags: file, vhdl

Supposing I've got a file filled with data separated by a tabulation (in this format):

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
```

and I'd like to read these data in pairs from a single line, so that result would be as follows:

```
var1=1;
var2=2;
var1=3;
var2=4;
var1=5;
var2=6;
```

How am I supposed to work? Right now my code works for a single data on a single line (see following):

```
read_from_file: process(clk)
  variable input_data: natural;
  variable ILine: line;
begin
  for i in 0 to NSAMPLES-1 loop
    readline (input_vectors, ILine);
    read(ILine, input_data);
  end loop;
end process;
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call the `read` function again.
For example:

```
read_from_file: process(clk)
  variable input_data_column1: natural;
  variable input_data_column2: natural;
  variable ILine: line;
begin
  for i in 0 to NSAMPLES-1 loop
    readline (input_vectors, ILine);
    read(ILine, input_data_column1);
    read(ILine, input_data_column2);
    -- Now you can do things like conv_std_logic_vector(input_data_column1, bitwidth) etc
  end loop;
end process;
```

Note: I am not positive if any whitespace will be accepted. Spaces have worked for me.

Comment: Won't the read(ILine, input_data_columnX) function operate on the following line when secondly called?

Comment: No, you use `readline` to get the next line into your buffer for processing. `read` works within the current line that you have active.

Comment: You can see the remains of `ILine` by inserting `report "ILine: '" & ILine.all & "'";` at different places in the loop. Btw. it works fine with different kind of white-spaces, and both Win and Linux newline.

Comment: @MortenZilmer  Yet 1076-2008 Appendix D tells us "The use of the following constructs may lead to nonportable VHDL descriptions: ...— Processes that communicate via file I/O, including TEXTIO". 16.4 Package TEXTIO "...The language does not define the representation of the end of a line. An implementation shall allow all possible values of types CHARACTER and STRING to be written to a file. However, as an implementation is permitted to use certain values of types CHARACTER and STRING as line delimiters, it might not be possible to read these values from a TEXT file." Which implementation?

Comment: @DavidKoontz: Thanks.  So it actually means there is no implementation independent way to create input text files with newlines understood as delimiter by READLINE.  But I assume LF will work in most implementations, as with ModelSim that I used.

Comment: @MortenZilmer format_effector 0x09 <= x <= 0x0d. 15.3 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters "The language does not define what causes the end of a line. However if, for a given implementation, the end of a line is signified by one or more characters, then these characters shall be format effectors other than horizontal tabulation. In any case, a sequence of one or more format effectors other than horizontal tabulation shall cause at least one end-of-line." Extra lines, possibly abrogated or run on lines. POSIX fgets() or equivalent is widely used and LF safe, not guaranteed portable.